# Wget a script and run it with parameters

Tags: bash, wget

My question is similar to [Wget a script and run it](https://serverfault.com/questions/226386/wget-a-script-and-run-it) but i want to additionally pass some parameters to the script. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
wget -qO - http://example.com/script.sh | bash -s param1 param2 ...
```

According to man BASH(1).

> If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain  after  option processing, then commands are read from the standard input.  This option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive  shell  or  when reading input through a pipe

You can try it with a test file

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$@"
$ python3 -m http.server 1234
```

And from another shell

```
$ wget -qO - http://localhost:1234/script.sh | bash -s param1 param2 ...
param1 param2 param3 ...
```

Make sure to stop the local http server afterward.

EDIT: updating the answer based on @Gordon Davisson's comment.

Comment: `bash $0 param1 param2` will generally work, but mostly by accident. In a normal interactive bash shell, `$0` will expand to "-bash". `bash -bash` runs `bash` with the options `-b`, `-a`, `-s`, and `-h`. `-s` is actually the thing you want here -- it basically tells `bash` to run commands from standard input, and pass the remaining args to the script. The other options, `-b`, `-a`, and `-h`, are irrelevant and mostly harmless. But as I said, it's mostly by accident that this works; you really should just use `bash -s param1 param2`.